# oscpu is undifiend in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, operating-system

I am try to get the users operating system and their version, So I used the `navigator` in javascript. By using the `oscpu` I can get the operating system details in firefox. But return a undefined error in chorme,

This is my code,

```
<script>  
(function () {
    alert(navigator.oscpu);
  });
</script>
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinodvt22/2gab8vhp/)**

How to fix this issues ? or any other method to detect the OS ?

Comment: There is no standard for what the navigator object returns, it might be anything, so is not reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this to detect your OS:

```
<script>  
(function () {
    alert(window.navigator.oscpu || window.navigator.platform);
  });
</script>
```

That should tell you about the OS, in my case it alerts this:

[image]